# How expand my session array to have more value?

Tags: php, arrays, session

Currently I am able to set and keep the name and price of the product being selected into my session array. I need to expand such that I can keep even the quantity and id. I dont know how to have more values stored into the same array such that if possible the key being id? Secondly I would need to check if the user press again then just add on the quantity and the rest of the information remains the same?

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$price = isset($_GET['price']) ? $_GET['price'] : "";
$quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']) ? $_GET['quantity'] : "";

/*
 * check if the 'cart' session array was created
 * if it is NOT, create the 'cart' session array
 */
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
}

// check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
if(array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['cart_items'])){
    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
    header('Location: products.php?action=exists&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}

// else, add the item to the array
else{
    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]=$price;

    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
    header('Location: products.php?action=added&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}
```

Comment: its array like any other

Comment: I prefer array so that say my key is the $id then rest followed by quantity, price, name etc. I need to store them dynamically just like how I am doing it now. Next I need for loop to extract each information.

Comment: `$price = $_GET['price']` just a tip as you move forward, don't let the user set their own price - you might lose money that way.

Comment: Yes so how to set that not be get cause it will be link they submit right?

Comment: I dont understand why its being down voted when I have shown what I have done and given my codes its really unfair to simply downvote question with requirement and codes in to show my effort done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use a [multidimensional array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-112).

```
// else, add the item to the array
else{
    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['price']=$price;

    if (!empty($quantity)){
        $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['quantity']=$quantity;
    }

    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
    header('Location: products.php?action=added&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}
```

Update:
In order to access deeper dimensions of an array, you could use a nested loop.

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $name=>$value){
    foreach($value as $key => $val){
        echo "$name : $key = $val <br/>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: How to read those values as currently I just do this foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $name=>$value){ so for the new method how to receive the values?

Comment: tried your method but when I run the foreach its not printing anything at all.

Comment: This foreach foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $name=>$value){
    foreach($value as $key => $val){
        echo "$name : $key = $val <br/>\n";
    }
} is not printing anything? Can I like get for each name the price, quantity in one shot